# Esempi di uso di "asticella" in senso figurato

Tags: word-usage

Ascoltando le notizie sulla RAI, ho osservato che si usava la parola "asticella" in senso figurato, con un significato che dal contesto si poteva capire che era più o meno quello di "livello di esigenza". Non ho però trovato questo senso figurato sui dizionari che ho consultato. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: potreste fare alcuni esempi di uso del vocabolo "asticella" con questo senso figurato?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'asticella è la sbarra utilizzata nei salti in alto o in salto con l'asta.
L'asticella è quindi un risultato da raggiungere e viene utilizzato a tal scopo.

Simile significato ha "soglia" che indica il limite della porta o dell'ingresso

Esempio:
Per dare il via a questo progetto bisogna superare l'asticella (o la soglia) dei 20.000€

"Alzare l'asticella" ha il significato letterale di "raise the bar" che mi sembra sia abbastanza utilizzato nella lingua inglese

http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/A/asticella.shtml